# Twig Fatal Error

Tags: twig

I have a big problem. I use a Twig templating but now I see the error page on my screen.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'You must set a loader first.' in C:\wampd\www\projects\weborangoo\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php on line 622`( ! )

`LogicException: You must set a loader first. in C:\wampd\www\projects\weborangoo\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php on line 622`

But my loader looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Ilib\Template;

use Twig_Loader_Filesystem;
use Twig_Environment;

class Template extends Twig_Environment {

    public $template;
    public $loader;
    public $cache_dir = 'templates/cache';

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();  

    \Twig_Autoloader::register();

    $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( 'templates' );
    $this->twig   = new Twig_Environment( $this->loader ,  array ( 'cache'  =>  $this->cache_dir ));

    }

    public function display($name, array $context = array()) {
    parent::display($name, $context); }

   }
```

Where can the problem be? I need to show the data in the template, but the data is an array, so I don't know where the mistake is.